# Adobe AIR 15: embedding fonts

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, fonts, air, flash-builder

I donwloaded Adobe AIR 15 SDK and added it to Flash Builder 4.7 as described here:

http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-builder/kb/overlay-air-sdk-flash-builder.html

Now I'm trying to embed a font into my ActionScript project like this:

```
    [Embed(source="../embed/MyFont.ttf", 
    fontName = "MyFont", 
    advancedAntiAliasing="true", 
    embedAsCFF="false")]
    private static var MyFont:Class;
```

but I'm getting a compile error (on no particular line):

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
invalid Unicode range 'ENGLISHRANGE'    MyApplication       line 0  Flex Problem
```

I also tried to set the unicode range explicitely like so:

```
    [Embed(source="../embed/MyFont.ttf", 
    fontName = "MyFont", 
    unicodeRange = "U+0020-U+007E",
    advancedAntiAliasing="true", 
    embedAsCFF="false")]
    private static var MyFont:Class;
```

but the error I get is the same.

I noted that the air-config.xml does not contain the `<fonts>` element anymore - maybe this is related?

how do I properly embed fonts in an ActionScript (not flex) project with AIR 15?

Comment: First are you getting the same error when compiling an empty project?

Comment: Do you get the same error when you attempt to embed a common font such as Arial?